# How to point domain names to S3 objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I would like to create multiple webpages in a single S3 bucket and access them by different domains.

For example, I have S3 objects:

- /my-bucket/page1/index.html
- /my-bucket/page2/index.html
- /my-bucket/page3/index.html

That can be accessed like that:

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/page1/index.html
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/page2/index.html
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/page3/index.html

Is it possible to access those S3 objects by domain:

- https://www.page1.com/index.html
- https://www.page2.com/index.html
- https://www.page3.com/index.html

Comment: What are the advantages to this that you see versus a single S3 bucket per website/domain?

Comment: I have around 200 tiny websites to host, creating S3 buckets for each is messy. Also, by default, AWS customers can provision up to 100 buckets per AWS accout.

Comment: Also keep in mind that unless you own the domain AND the bucket name (they must match), a single static website per-bucket won't work. Often it's not hard to own both, but I have come across domains that I own (or have worked on), where the bucket was already reserved by someone else - this is why cloudfront is better imo.

Comment: You can use Terraform to provision all the tiny site and request limit increases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. SInce you are essentially trying to create multiple websites within a single s3 bucket, you'll want to use cloudfront to accomplish this.

Bit more complicated than setting up a single s3 bucket static website, but not hard to do using the many examples/directions aws has.

Comment: If OP accepts the idea of creating a new CloudFront distribution for each folder in the bucket, and point that domain to the distribution endpoint, it should work. New costs involved though.